# Forced errors now showing in android xml files

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

For some reason my R file isn't being generated (I have tried clean and everything).  It was working before, but after a bunch of xml changes it stopped (I broke my usual rule of progressive development).  Anyhow for sanity I made error on purpose in my xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_discard"
        android:orderInCategory="6"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/deletefs"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/compose"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_compose"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/healthJournalCompose"/>

</menu>
```

I know @string/deletefs does not exist so Eclipse I would think would show an error or a warning but it is not.  What can I do to get the error to display

Comment: Try cleaning your project and build it. Sometimes the resources will not be properly refered until we clean the proj. And you would be aware that if there is any error in the xml the R.java would not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've accidentally turned off `Build Automatically`? XML errors are usually reported in the `Console` view.

The `Error Log` view *sometimes* shows problems that aren't in the other places, but it is usually full of internal Eclipse "errors" and warnings, so you'll probably want to clear it beforehand.